# Undefined array key

Tags: php

Estoy en un sistema de usuarios y un admian, cada uno tiene una _$session diferente pero una de las sesiones me sale con un error de (**Warning:** Undefined array key "ValidarIngresoUsuario" in **C:\xampp\htdocs\joel\login\views\paginas\documento.php** on **line 55**), el Sistema está funcionando sin problemas pero sin embargo aparece ese error en la pantalla. ¿Por qué será?

**NOTA:** Si ingreso con Admin, falla "ValidarIngresoUsuario" que es la variable $_SESSION de Usuario. Y si ingreso con Usuario, falla "ValidarIngreso" que es la variable $_SESSION de Admin.

[image: Aparece hasta el nombre del usuario sin problema pero con el error en pantalla]

**Código de documento.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$usuario1 = $_SESSION['ValidarIngreso'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['ValidarIngresoUsuario'];

if(!isset($usuario1)){
    if(isset($usuario)){
    }elseif(isset($usuario1)){

    }else{
        header('location:../../index.php?hoja=&error=');
    }
}
```

**Código de la validación de Usuarios y admin**

````
<?php

session_start();

require("conexion.php");

$usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
$pass = $_POST["password"];

$sql = mysqli_query($conectar,"SELECT * FROM registro WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");
    if($f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        if($pass == $f['password']){

            $_SESSION['ValidarIngresoUsuario'] = $usuario;

            header("location:../views/paginas/documento.php?arch=");
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;  
            $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;

        }elseif($pass == $f['adminpass']){

            $_SESSION['ValidarIngreso'] = $usuario;

            echo '<script>alert("BIENVENIDO ADMINISTRADOR")</script> ';
            echo "<script>location.href='../views/paginas/Inicio.php'</script>";
        }else{
            header("location:/joel/login/index.php?hoja=&error=ACTIVO");
        }
    }else{
        header("location:/joel/login/index.php?hoja=&error=ACTIVO");
    }

mysqli_close($conectar);

?>
```
````

Comment: No le veo sentido a asignar `$usuario1 = $_SESSION['...'];` y luego preguntar si esa variable existe `if(!isset($usuario1)) ...`. Obviamente si no están seteadas las variables de sesión, la asignación inicial dará error.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario. Decidí preguntar porque al iniciar sesion con admin, luego no iniciaba con usuario o viceversa porque se confundía, no sé si estaré en lo correcto pero de esa forma me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

cuando trabajas con variables de session debes siempre preguntar tanto si existe o si esta vacio. ya que php arrojara siempre un warning al no detectar la existencia de esa key en la session

```
if(isset($_SESSION['ValidarIngreso']) && !empty($_SESSION['ValidarIngreso'])){
        $usuario1 = $_SESSION['ValidarIngreso'];
}
if(isset($_SESSION['ValidarIngresoUsuario']) && !empty($_SESSION['ValidarIngresoUsuario'])){
        $usuario = $_SESSION['ValidarIngresoUsuario'];
}
```